# Array Data Reading Failed

Tags: arrays, for-loop, arduino, arduino-ide, usbserial

I am reading the data from a "Torque Wrench" using "USB Host Shield2.0" and Arduino UNO. I am receiving correct data from my "Torque Wrench" Data is receiving in a array.
But when I started reading data after "for" loop inside `Void loop()`  I am receiving incorrect data. I attached Both output pictures correct and incorrect data.

Basically I am read data from Torque Wrench and send to receiver using Nrf24l01. I am receiving incorrect data.

My question is :- Why I am reading Incorrect data outside "for" loop.

1. Correct Data inside "for" loop :- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB8Ov.png)
2. Incorrect Data outside "for" loop :- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbmit.png)

```
#include <SPI.h> // for SPI communication
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

#include <cdcacm.h>
#include <usbhub.h>

//#include "pgmstrings.h"

// Satisfy the IDE, which needs to see the include statment in the ino too.
#ifdef dobogusinclude
#include <spi4teensy3.h>
#endif
#include <SPI.h>



RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte address[6] = {'R','x','A','A','A','B'}; // the address the the module

class ACMAsyncOper : public CDCAsyncOper
{
public:
    uint8_t OnInit(ACM *pacm);
};

uint8_t ACMAsyncOper::OnInit(ACM *pacm)
{
    uint8_t rcode;
    // Set DTR = 1 RTS=1
    rcode = pacm->SetControlLineState(3);

    if (rcode)
    {
        ErrorMessage<uint8_t>(PSTR("SetControlLineState"), rcode);
        return rcode;
    }

    LINE_CODING  lc;
    lc.dwDTERate  = 9600;
    lc.bCharFormat  = 0;
    lc.bParityType  = 0;
    lc.bDataBits  = 8;

    rcode = pacm->SetLineCoding(&lc);

    if (rcode)
        ErrorMessage<uint8_t>(PSTR("SetLineCoding"), rcode);

    return rcode;
}

USB     Usb;
//USBHub     Hub(&Usb);
ACMAsyncOper  AsyncOper;
ACM           Acm(&Usb, &AsyncOper);




void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  radio.stopListening(); 

  #if !defined(__MIPSEL__)
  while (!Serial); 
#endif
  Serial.println("Start");

  if (Usb.Init() == -1)
      Serial.println("USB Not Connected");

  delay( 200 ); 
 

}

void loop() {
  
  

   Usb.Task();
 
    if( Acm.isReady()) {
       uint8_t rcode;

       /* reading the keyboard */
       if(Serial.available()) {
         uint8_t data= Serial.read();
         /* sending to the phone */
         rcode = Acm.SndData(1, &data);
         if (rcode)
            ErrorMessage<uint8_t>(PSTR("SndData"), rcode);
       }

       delay(10);

        uint8_t  buf[64];
        uint16_t rcvd = 64;
        char text[64];
        
        rcode = Acm.RcvData(&rcvd, buf);
         if (rcode && rcode != hrNAK)
            ErrorMessage<uint8_t>(PSTR("Ret"), rcode);

            if ( rcvd ) { 
           
             for(uint16_t i=0; i < rcvd; i++ ) 
              { 
               // Serial.print((char)buf[i]);  // correct Data read from torque wrench
                text[i] = (char)buf[i];
              }

              
              Serial.println(text);  // reading wrong data here
              
              //radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));   
              //Serial.println(text);               
            }
        delay(10);
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Character arrays *must* be null-terminated to count as C strings.
After the for loop, add `text[rcvd] = '\0';`
Also, your rcvd is fixed at 64. It needs to be one less than the array size for the null terminator to fit.

Comment: Hi, Still I am getting same issue(Incorrect data).